# Install Oracle Jdk

Tags: jdk, oracle

I'm newbie in ubuntu. Need to install a software for school project. Could someone guide me on installing jdk-20_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz.
Thanks.

Comment: You have an "aarch" machine? Mind that there is a generic topic about what to do with tar.gz files. Please use https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file for this q